# Is there a way to prevent apps from staying in Dock after quitting?

Tags: macos, dock

Certain OSX apps seem to have a tendency to stick around in the Dock, even though there's no user-facing setting to prevent this behavior. Is there a `defaults` command that prevents apps from enabling "Keep in Dock?"

I know about `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array` (intentionally empty), but this has to be run manually, and repeatedly. Any ideas?

Comment: How do You quit an app? If it was not kept in Dock before opening, hitting ⌘CMD + Q to close an app should remove icon form the Dock.

Comment: To date (27 March, 2019) each of the answers here fails the actually does something test. I know this comment sounds negative, because it is, but at the same time maybe it can save somebody some disappointment.

Comment: @MichaelWolf The highest voted answer (by @Shrihari) does what the OP is looking for. The question assumes that no UI exists to prevent the keep-in-dock behavior, thus they ask for a `defaults` command. That UI does exist tho and does exactly what is desired here.

Comment: @Constablebrew It doesn't. If you move an open app's position in the dock and then quit the app, its icon stays there, even if you have unchecked the option mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelWolf Dragging an icon is explicitly setting its position, thus saving it to the dock (and over-riding any preferences). Setting the preference to not show recent apps in dock and also not dragging an app icon does just what OP is asking for - the app icon goes away when the app is closed.

Answer (score 197):

I think I understand your problem.. Open System Preferences, Click on dock, uncheck "Show recent applications in dock". This should probably solve your problem.

Comment: This setting enabled itself when I upgraded from High Sierra to Catalina

Comment: On some versions of macOS you may need to logout and login again after changing the setting.

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is about.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant when I found this question @Jay. So tired of needing to tell unpinned apps to be removed from dock after quitting them!

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a per application basis?

Comment: thanks, I was an surprisingly awfully longtime looking for this answer

Answer (score 8):

Even after the below configuration, some applications might still run in background (. symbol in dock) &  appears in dock

> **Open System Preferences, Click on dock, uncheck "Show recent applications in dock"**

For instance, terminal/iterm2 they do not disappear from dock when closing from window.

For disappearing the application from dock, **Command key, ⌘ + Q**

so basically, some applications like in launchpad close immediately from dock as soon as they are closed from window but, if they don't disappear from dock then ⌘ + Q will be the solution

Comment: The only working solution I found.

Comment: works! what a relief now

Comment: This is it. Otherwise app still seems to sit in memory after all windows are closed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like in Mojave (10.14) the following will do the trick:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock show-recents -bool no
defaults write com.apple.dock recent-apps -array # intentionally empty
```

Comment: that feature didn't exist in 2016

Answer (score 1):

Either the app needs to be quit with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, or you need to just drag the icon out of the dock, and it'll be gone.

Comment: No, there is a right click, "Remove from dock" item. I'm asking for preventing this from even being kept in the dock to begin with.

Comment: @KevinSuttle it's not supposed to be. The only way it would happen is if the app's dock icon gets moved, or you right click on it and tell it to stay there.

Comment: Aha, the "if the app's dock icon gets moved" is the trigger. I wonder if that behavior can be prevented.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Our IT dept uses a utility called MacManage that will re-add the icon to the dock every 15 minutes, even if manually quit and unchecking `keep in dock`.

Comment: @nipponese are you serious?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton I would not joke about something as aggravating as that.

Comment: @nipponese What an unbelievably crap IT department.