# Moving an icon on the dock triggers "Keep in Dock", any way to prevent this?

Tags: macos, dock, icon, settings

If you `'right click' an icon on the dock > hover 'Options' > un-check "Keep in Dock"` and proceed to `drag the icon to move it`, what happens is the "Keep in Dock" option becomes checked once again.

This is annoying because I do not want closed applications to be on my dock, yet I want to be able to organize my dock when application are open.

The issue was briefly mentioned in the comment section of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224236/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-apps-from-staying-in-dock-after-quitting) thread with no apparent solution.

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Why not move it first and then change the setting?

At one time, I needed to keep my dock updated with something that changed frequently.  I just used a corn job to periodically replace the dock’s plait with a saved copy.  That would presumably only help with things that stay in the dock, though.

Answer (score -1):

For me the follow worked:

- Launch "Launchpad"
- while Launchpad is open

  - remove the Icon you want to rearrange from the dock by dragging it upwards on the screen
  - re-add the Icon from the Launchpad list at the position you wanna have it

good luck.

Comment: Where do you disable "Keep in Dock" during that process?